# Expat living in Germany, working abroad

Tags: germany, health-insurance

I have very specific situation.

I moved to Germany last year, I am EU citizen, I work internationally out of Europe for an American company and I stay most of the time abroad. I have private corporate provided international health insurance and I earn more than 70 K Euro a year. I am 53 years old.

1. From above I understand that I do not need to pay in AOK for health insurance since I have higher earnings and I have private international coverage health insurance.
2. I hear that there is a way to pay approx 50 Euro additionally to AOK, parallel to private one, so I am insured with AOK also while I am in Germany and it will keep me in the system for time when I will be above 55 years old and will be able to be in the system when I will not have this job anymore.
   Am I right about this extra 50 Euro to pay to AOK parallel to my private insurance??

Or what are my options so I can ensure to have AOK once I stop working abroad and will permanently settle in Germany.

Comment: Welcome, Alex. My edit was of the word 'leaving' as the rest of your question says you're living there (leben), not verlassen. Entschuldigung if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi, Giorgio, I am resident in Germany and my family is there, they have their own AOK insurance, but I am working abroad and spend more than half year working abroad.

Comment: Please note that AOK is a *specific* public health insurance company. The easiest and maybe most reliable way is to ask them, in one of their offices in person. Other public healthcare providers may have different terms.

Comment: @nvoigt It is very likely that the ability to pay additional premiums to remain *Gesetzlichversichert* is either mandated by law (and applies to all insurance companies), or does not exist. (But you are right about "just ask them".)